# Trouble reading LAZ downloaded from NOAA LiDAR database

Tags: r, lidar, noaa, laz

I am attempting to download the raw point cloud of a LiDAR acquisition from NOAA's Office of Coastal Management's LiDAR database using R.  The data download with out error, but when I read in the laz files as a LASCatalog, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: only 148 bytes until point block when trying to read 12423 bytes into header.vlrs[1].data
WARNING: only 0 bytes until point block after reading 2 of 3 vlrs. skipping remaining vlrs ...
ERROR: this file was compressed with an experimental version of laszip
ERROR: please contact 'martin.isenburg@rapidlasso.com' for assistance.
ERROR: cannot open lasreaderlas with file name 'C:\Users\SCMCKENZIE\Downloads\Test.laz'
Error: LASlib internal error. See message above.
Error in !x@PHB[["Global Encoding"]][["WKT"]] : invalid argument type
```

Doing some Googling, I believe it is related to this [this error](https://groups.google.com/g/lastools/c/x8wF-sijCDQ?pli=1), which suggests that it is not in fact an issue with LASzip, but rather an issue with downloading from NOAA's AWS server.  I found [this blog](https://geozoneblog.wordpress.com/2019/05/01/bulk-lidar-download-on-digital-coast/), whose comments suggest that it may be possible to download via FTP instead, but I have not been able to figure out how to do that.  Any advice on other ways to download these data?  Below is a reproducible example of my workflow in R.

```
##install and/or necessary package##
if(!require(lidR)){
  install.packages("lidR")
}

##Download Text File of URLs with point cloud files##
download.file("https://noaa-nos-coastal-lidar-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/laz/geoid18/9305/urllist9305.txt", "lidarlist.txt")
lazlist<-read.table("lidarlist.txt")
download.file(lazlist$V1[9], "Test.laz")

test<-readLAScatalog("Test.laz") #Throws Error
test<-readLAS("Test.laz") #Crashes R
```

Comment: Hate to say it but "works for me". lidR package 4.0.3 on R 4.3.1... No errors, no crashes. `test` is 18.16 million points, 1.1Gb memory, etc etc.

Comment: No need to apologize; that is good information.  I just upgraded R to version 4.3.1 and lidR to version 4.0.4, but I still get both the error with `readLAScatalog()` and the crash with `readLAS()`  But the fact it works on your machine with the same version of R and an older version of lidR suggests that it may be an issue with my machine.  I will continue investigating and report back if I figure anything out.

Comment: Then try to update `rlas`. This is the package that performs the I/O. Not lidR.

Comment: Thanks @JRR, I tried updating both `Rtools` and `rlas`, but the error persisted.  I then tried downloading directly from NOAA's website, and I was able to open the laz file without, which convinces me that this is absolutely an issue with NOAA's AWS server.  Thanks so much for your help and for the amazing `lidR` package!

Comment: Digging a little deeper, I think that the issue may a matter of which method is selected in `download.file()`  It looks like the default is to use libcurl. @Spacedman, I would be curious what download method you used and whether you are operating on windows or linux. Nonetheless, I resolved the issue by downloading via UGet as suggested by NOAA.   Thanks for all of the help.